# unable to find an entry point named 'interlockedexchange'

Tags: c#, .net, windows, 64-bit, dllimport

I built an application in c# vs2005 .net .

Everything works fine when i run the application in win 32 bit, But
when running the application in win 64  it crashes while trying to call
the pinvoke interlockedexchange(which is within the kernel32.dll) function .

This is the exception :
unable to find an entry point named 'interlockedexchange'

I didnt find the interlockedexchange function within the kernel32.dll under system32 directory but it was found under the syswow64 directory(in the kernel32.dll) .

I guess that the .net runtime is configured to the system32 directory and not to the syswow64 .
How is it possible to change this configuration ? Can you think of any other problem that could cause this?
any help would be appreciated!
thanks ,

Miki Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are set on using InterlockedExchange and want the 32-bit version, you can change your project settings to force it to run as 32-bit.  Go to the "Build" tab in the project settings and change "Platform target" to x86.  It will then run as 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your question, but why not call `System.Threading.Interlocked.Exhange()` rather than resorting to P/Invoke?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I need to set a Shared Memory Intptr (pointer) and far as i know the Interlocked.Exhange can change only .net variables

Comment: @Miki, this is not the case, the .NET Interlocked.Exchange can operate on any memory location whatsoever. If it's .NET memory, you have to pin it first, of course. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116790/c-sharp-interlocked-exchange/5589515#5589515.