# Passing bytes by reference from C# into C++/CLI wrapper to call the InterlockedOr8 function

Tags: c#, c++, .net, .net-core, visual-c++

I am trying to pass bytes by reference from C# such that I can call the atomic operation [InterlockedOr8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockedor8) on them. I have the following static library in C++:

*Bitwise.h*:

```
char EightBitOr(char volatile* destination, char value);
```

*Bitwise.cpp*:

```
#include "Bitwise.h"

char EightBitOr(char volatile* destination, char value)
{
    return InterlockedOr8(destination, value);
}
```

I am calling it from this C++/CLI wrapper DLL:

*Wrapper.h*:

```
#include "..\Bitwise\Bitwise.h"

using namespace System;

namespace Wrapper {
    public ref class Bitwise
    {
    public:
        static char InterlockedEightBitOr(volatile char* destination, char value);
    };
}
```

*Wrapper.cpp*:

```
#include "Wrapper.h"

char Wrapper::Bitwise::InterlockedEightBitOr(volatile char* destination, char value)
{
    return EightBitOr(destination, value);
}
```

I am trying to call the wrapper from a .NET 5.0 (Core) C# Console Application as follows:

```
var map = new byte[268435456];
Bitwise.InterlockedEightBitOr(ref map[0], (byte)1);
```

But I get the following error:

> CS0570    'Bitwise.InterlockedEightBitOr(sbyte*, sbyte)' is not supported
> by the language

I also noticed the wrapper has translated the method signature into `sbyte Bitwise.InterlockedEightBitOr(sbyte* destination, sbyte value);` whereas I'd much rather pass unsigned bytes and I am not sure how to change this behavior. Anyways, I was wondering if anyone knew if there is any way I can pass bytes by reference into this CLI wrapper? What changes would I need to make?

Comment: Is it really a good idea calling a method of another dll for an intrinsic? There is a "cost" you pay to call a dll method.

Comment: @xanatos I know. I want to benchmark that cost and see how bad it is compared to, say, using a lock...

Comment: I@Alexandru Aaaah... Can't you simply use a `Interlocked.Or` with `int` (at least benchmark it)

Comment: @xanatos Believe me, for my use case, that would require more memory or computing power, and I really want to nail this interview question beyond anything this guy has ever seen.

Comment: Start by typing `unsigned char` instead...

Comment: @aybe Using `unsigned char*` or `Byte%` throws compile time errors because `InterlockedOr8` expects a `volatile char*`. I know, you might ask me to typecast next, but if I do, will that break the atomicity of the `InterlockedOr8` function? In other words, will the type-casted value point to the same memory location as its original counterpart in the `map` array?

Comment: Okay, what about first adjusting your signature until it's accepted maybe by trying `array<...>^` and then trying `interior_ptr` to make the next call happy?