# Interlocked.CompareExchange with enum

Tags: c#, interlocked

I'm trying to use [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with this enum:

```
public enum State {
    Idle,
    Running,
    //...
}
```

The following code doesn't compile, but that's what I want do do:

```
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref state, State.Running, State.Idle) != State.Idle) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to run - not idle");
}
```

Sure I can use a int instead of the enum and use a property:

```
private int state = (int)State.Idle;
public State { get { return (State)state; } }
```

Then cast the enums to a int:

```
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref state, (int)State.Running, (int)State.Idle) !=  (int)State.Idle) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to run - not idle");
}
```

But are there better ways to do this?

Comment: What you show (treating it as an `int` and casting) is basically exactly what I do.

Comment: @MarcGravell: basically?

Comment: To be honest it's not really that big a deal. Personally I would just keep it as an `enum` but cast it before you do the exchange.

Comment: @James you can't do that; the field needs to be `int` to use it as `ref` in the call. You can't cast during a `ref`.

Comment: @James: That will kill the reason to use `CompareExchange`.

Comment: @joe ok, "exactly" what I do. Better?

Comment: @MarcGravell: sorry, just wanted to know if there's more than the shown code...

Comment: @MarcGravell I was meaning as a local var (pretty much what the OP has already).

Comment: Is it possible to change your `enum` to a `class` that uses `static readonly` instances like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119714/when-to-use-enums-and-when-to-replace-them-with-a-class-with-static-members)? You can implement the backing integer values as well if necessary.

Comment: @James in the example, it is not a local var - it is an instance field

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: That's indeed a good idea. The only pain here is that I still want to use the enum for the `public State { get; }` property. So I have a enum and some constants in parallel, but that doesn't hurt much.

Comment: Out of interest, why not just use `Interlocked.Exchange(ref state, (int)State.Running)` instead? In this code, it would result in the same logic, right?

Comment: @Neo - because the method doesn't have an overload with a generic type constraint of 'struct' or 'unmanaged'. Only reference types work for the generic `Interlocked.Exchange<T>()` overload.  Here's a workaround: `Interlocked.Exchange(ref Unsafe.As<State, int>(ref state), (int) State.Running)`.  See my answer below for similar solution to question being asked (i.e. `CompareExchange`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make it simple, no :-)

Sadly C#/.NET consider `enum`s as full type, partially disconnected from their base type. Every time you try to do something "fancy" on an `enum` you encounter some barrier.

Answer (score 20):

It's possible from IL, and it's possible to create a helper method for this that can be used from C#.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Threading;

static class CompareExchangeEnumImpl<T>
{
    public delegate T dImpl(ref T location, T value, T comparand);
    public static readonly dImpl Impl = CreateCompareExchangeImpl();

    static dImpl CreateCompareExchangeImpl()
    {
        var underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
        var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod(string.Empty, typeof(T), new[] { typeof(T).MakeByRefType(), typeof(T), typeof(T) });
        var ilGenerator = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
        ilGenerator.Emit(
            OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(Interlocked).GetMethod(
                "CompareExchange",
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
                null,
                new[] { underlyingType.MakeByRefType(), underlyingType, underlyingType },
                null));
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return (dImpl)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(dImpl));
    }
}

public static class InterlockedEx
{
    public static T CompareExchangeEnum<T>(ref T location, T value, T comparand)
    {
        return CompareExchangeEnumImpl<T>.Impl(ref location, value, comparand);
    }
}

public enum Foo
{
    X,
    Y,
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo x = Foo.X;
        Foo y = Foo.Y;
        y = InterlockedEx.CompareExchangeEnum(ref x, y, Foo.X);
        Console.WriteLine("x: " + x);
        Console.WriteLine("y: " + y);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
x: Y
y: X
```

This just forwards the arguments to the correct `Interlocked.Exchange` overload. It fails badly if `T` isn't really an enum type, or its underlying type doesn't have an `Interlocked.Exchange` overload.

The generated IL is verifiable, at least according to PEVerify, as can be checked by making this use `AssemblyBuilder` and saving the result to a file.

Comment: @DarthVader Why not? I haven't ever had a reason to use `Interlocked.Exchange` with enums, but I do have other cases where there's a clear and correct way to do something, CIL allows it, but C# doesn't. In that case, I don't think C# is the right tool for the job, so I don't use C#.

Comment: How naughty! But I love it and copied it straight into my code :) Now, can you also do a `Thread.VolatileRead(myEnum)`?

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky Sure, I don't see why not. It should be easy to adapt my answer to handle that. There are a lot of other methods that could also make sense to add, I don't think it'll benefit SO to include all of them here in an answer. :)

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky see modernized Net Core response below.  Just as easy to drop in and outperforms the Net6 native implementation by 1000x

Answer (score 6):

`Interlocked` operations on **enum** are no problem:

```
public enum State { Idle, Running }

unsafe State CompareExchange(ref State target, State v, State cmp)
{
    fixed (State* p = &target)
        return (State)Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref *(int*)p, (int)v, (int)cmp);
}
```

See my full answer and discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5589515/147511

Answer (score 5):

> But are there better ways to do this?

I use a class instead of Enum:

```
public class DataCollectionManagerState
{
    public static readonly DataCollectionManagerState Off = new DataCollectionManagerState() { };
    public static readonly DataCollectionManagerState Starting = new DataCollectionManagerState() { };
    public static readonly DataCollectionManagerState On = new DataCollectionManagerState() { };

    private DataCollectionManagerState() { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (this == Off) return "Off";
        if (this == Starting) return "Starting";
        if (this == On) return "On";

        throw new Exception();
    }
}

public class DataCollectionManager
{
    private static DataCollectionManagerState _state = DataCollectionManagerState.Off;

    public static void StartDataCollectionManager()
    {
        var originalValue = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _state, DataCollectionManagerState.Starting, DataCollectionManagerState.Off);
        if (originalValue != DataCollectionManagerState.Off)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("StartDataCollectionManager can be called when it's state is Off only. Current state is \"{0}\".", originalValue.ToString()));
        }

        // Start Data Collection Manager ...

        originalValue = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _state, DataCollectionManagerState.On, DataCollectionManagerState.Starting);
        if (originalValue != DataCollectionManagerState.Starting)
        {
            // Your code is really messy
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected error occurred. Current state is \"{0}\".", originalValue.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is often a good idea if the enum is controlling lots of things as a kind of strategy object. One symptom is lots of switches on the enum in different places.

Answer (score 3):

## Using `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5589515/5185376) a pretty good related answer going into depth.

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;

public static class InterlockedEx
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Enum equivalent of <see cref="Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref Int32, Int32, Int32)"/> and <see cref="Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref Int64, Int64, Int64)"/>
    /// </summary>
    public static TEnum CompareExchange<TEnum>(ref TEnum location, TEnum value, TEnum comparand)
        where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        return Unsafe.SizeOf<TEnum>() switch
        {
            // .NET does not support 1- and 2-byte atomic operations as there
            // is no common hardware support for that.
            4 => CompareExchange32Bit(ref location, value, comparand),
            8 => CompareExchange64Bit(ref location, value, comparand),
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException("Only enums with an underlying type of 4 bytes or 8 bytes are allowed to be used with Interlocked")
        };

        static TEnum CompareExchange32Bit(ref TEnum location, TEnum value, TEnum comparand)
        {
            int comparandRaw = Unsafe.As<TEnum, int>(ref comparand);
            int valueRaw = Unsafe.As<TEnum, int>(ref value);
            ref int locationRaw = ref Unsafe.As<TEnum, int>(ref location);
            int returnRaw = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref locationRaw, valueRaw, comparandRaw);
            return Unsafe.As<int, TEnum>(ref returnRaw);
        }

        static TEnum CompareExchange64Bit(ref TEnum location, TEnum value, TEnum comparand)
        {
            long comparandRaw = Unsafe.As<TEnum, long>(ref comparand);
            long valueRaw = Unsafe.As<TEnum, long>(ref value);
            ref long locationRaw = ref Unsafe.As<TEnum, long>(ref location);
            long returnRaw = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref locationRaw, valueRaw, comparandRaw);
            return Unsafe.As<long, TEnum>(ref returnRaw);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I abstracted the [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#overloads) away and used a collection of interfaces.

- `ILockManager<T>`: Contains all individual locks for each Enum
- `ILock`: The lock for an individual Enum
- `ILockReleaser`: Responsible for releasing the lock when it is acquired

### Interfaces

```
public interface ILockManager<T> where T : Enum {
    bool TryAcquire(T key, out ILockReleaser lockReleaser);
}

public interface ILock {
    string Name { get; }

    bool TryAcquire(out ILockReleaser lockReleaser);
}

public interface ILockReleaser {
    void Release();
}
```

### Example

You would use this the following (just like a normal Interlock):

```
enum FooLocks {
    FooOne,
    FooTwo,
}

public class FooClass {
    
    private readonly ILockManager<FooLocks> _lockManager;
    public FooClass(ILockManager<FooLocks> lockManager) {
        _lockManager = lockManager;
    }

    public void RunByOneThreadOnly() {
        if (_lockManager.TryAcquire(FooLocks.FooOne, out var activeLock))
            return;

        try {
            /* Your code */
        } finally {
            activeLock.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

### Implementation

Here is the implementation of the interfaces for `ILockManager<T>`, `ILock` and `ILockReleaser`:

```
public class LockManager<T> : ILockManager<T> where T : Enum {
    public bool TryAcquire(T key, out ILockReleaser lockReleaser) => _locks[key].TryAcquire(out lockReleaser);

    // Create a lock for each enum value
    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<T, ILock> _locks = new Dictionary<T, ILock>((Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)) as T[]).Select(e => new KeyValuePair<T, ILock>(e, new Lock(e.ToString()))));
}

public class Lock : ILock, ILockReleaser {
    public string Name { get; }

    public Lock(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    
    public bool TryAcquire(out ILockReleaser lockReleaser) {
        lockReleaser = this;
        return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _curLock, 1, 0) != 0;
    }

    public void Release() {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _curLock, 0);
    }

    public override string ToString() => Name;

    private int _curLock;
}
```

### Remarks

This does not support flagged Enums such as `FooLocks.FooOne | FooLocks.FooTwo`. it would be possible to support them, however, I think that would abstract too much and I would leave it at the consuming class to handle flagged enums.